# PHP - Call to undefined function requiring a file from a different folder and using namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, directory, undefined, fatal-error

**EDIT: I removed namespaces and it still doesn't work. If i move the file in the same folder with blog.php, it works. For the moment, I'm connecting to the database again in the admin file, but I supose that's not a solution.**

This is my first question posted. I've started to learn PHP recently and i really like it but i'm stuck now with a problem. I've searched for answers but i couldn't find anything related.

So here's my problem.

I'm trying to build a simple blog and I want to create an admin section. So i created a new folder 'admin' and a file 'index.php' inside it. When I require the 'blog.php' file which connects to the database, I get the error:

**'Fatal error: Call to undefined function Blog\DB\connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\blog.php on line 5'** .

In a file db.php which contains all my database related functions I use the namespace Blog\DB. **What I dont't really get is that if i move the admin 'index.php' file in the same folder as blog.php it works.**

Here is the code from both files.

**blog.php** :

```
 <?php 
    require 'functions.php';
    require 'db.php';
    //Connect to the db
    $conn = Blog\DB\connect($config);
    if (!$conn) die('Problem connecting to the db!');
    ?>
```

**admin/index.php**

```
<?php 
require '../blog.php';
?>
```

**db.php uses:**

```
namespace Blog\DB;
```

Thank you!

Comment: check namespaces  and/or add use Blog\DB\connect

Comment: php namespaces (`things\like\these`) have (unfortunately) nothing to do with file and directory paths.

Comment: Then why if I move the file in the same folder with blog.php it works?

Comment: I checked the namespaces and also tried to add the namespace to blog.php. It doesn't work.

Comment: What namespace are you using for this file, and what namespace is defined in db.php? This is 100% a namespacing issue.

Comment: see whether you have made any typo.

Comment: I checked and i didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$conn = Blog\DB\connect($config);
```

to

```
$conn = \Blog\DB\connect($config);
```

Even though not sure if that should work then as I don't think it's namespacing problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this ....

```
require __DIR__ . '/../db.php';
```

I am also working with PHP and ran into same issue as you. I tried the above line and it worked.

Note: I am working without aliases and namespaces.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I just added 
`require '../db.php';`
in admin/index.php
It solves the problem, but I dont know why that problem occured.
My best guess is that when we require files that uses namespace(like your blog.php uses Blog/DB) we have to require files where we set that namespace( db.php )

Answer (score -1):

I recently came across the same problem going through the same PHP lessons. The problem is including an include in a sub-directory causes file path problems. It has nothing to do with namespaces.

replace `require 'db.php';` in blog.php with:

```
 require __DIR__ . '/db.php';
```

if you're running a PHP version lower than 5.3 use:

```
 require dirname(__FILE__) . '/db.php';
```

now when it is included in /admin/index.php the reference will be correct for both the blog and the admin sub-directory.

Comment: please include a reason if you're going to down vote... if you know of a 'better' solution it would be nice if you posted it. Nonconstructive down-voting is counter-productive.